# How to find what files were deployed if package.xml is not available?

Tags: apex, deployment, migration-tool

How do I find the list of files that were deployed to my sandbox if somebody else deployed components to using Force migration tool and I don't have access to `package.xml` file that they used.

Below is the screen I see in my sandbox.

[image]

Comment: The `Setup Audit Trail` (search in quick find) can help you at least figure out what changes were made.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case no one else answers, in your shoes I would comb through the `Setup Audit Trail`. There will be a link called `Download setup audit trail for last six months (Excel .csv file)`.

You will need to download the csv file to view the number of changes you are talking about. It will also make it easier to filter on some of the fields for ease of consumption. Specifically I would filter on the `User` and `Date` columns, which should all match the `Deployed By` and `End Time` (?) respectively.

I would expect the following `Sections` to be especially informative:

- `Apex Class`

  - Created MyClass1 Apex Class code
  - Changed MyClass2 Apex Class code
  - Deleted MyClass3 Apex Class code
- `Custom Objects`

  - Created custom object: My Object Label
  - Created custom field Field Label (Text) on My Object Label

I'm sure you can discover many more that will help you deduce the components of the `InboundChangeSet`.

Comment: You are correct. Setup audit trail is somewhat helpful in this case.